# ZipArchive PHP - constantly getting errors despite following every answer on stackoverflow so far

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I create a file with a MySQL query. Now trying to download it as a zip. I want to include a 2nd file, but I can't even get one to work.

WinRar just fails. On another windows system, I got an error saying the archive is empty, even though the `file_exists`.

```
$file = '/temp/' . $temp_filename;
if(file_exists($file)) {
            $zipname = 'myfile_' . $name . '_' . $date . '.zip';
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
            $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
            $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);
            $zip->close();

            // also tried $zip->addFile($file,basename($file));


            //header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/zip');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($zipname));
            //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            //header('Expires: 0');
            //header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            //header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');
            ob_clean(); // also tried commenting this
            flush(); // and this
            readfile($zipname);
            // exit(); // tried with and without exit.
}


Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=test.zip
Content-Type:application/zip
Date:Sat, 28 Feb 2015 01:04:57 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1+sury.org~precise+1
```

Comment: Enable error_reporting, try it per CLI first to see if it does anything. What's `wget -S` showing? Showcase a hexdump of any resulting zip.

Comment: @mario I added the header from google chrome. Does that help. I'll try to get the hexdump. Gotta google some sstuff.

Answer (score 0):

ZipArchive::CREATE will fail if file exists, try:

```
$zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
```